# Excel Worksheet Split

Tags: vba, excel, macros

So I need a bit of help with an existing macro.

I need to split a workbook's multiple worksheets into multiple files (not based on worksheet name).

**The project:** It deals with very sensitive HR/performance data, and I need to send 1000s of employees' data to their individual managers (about 100 managers who can only see their team's data, and no one else's), so I need about 100 files split (1 for each manager).

**The file:**
- Many different tabs, separated by role.
- First column is a unique identifier made by concatenating the Manager's name with the job title ex. John Stevens_Office Manager

**The task:** John Stevens will have team members in many different job roles, and needs all that data in one file, separated into tabs by job role. My current macro does half of this (splits the file, but does not unite).

It also doesn't delete out the other tabs from the file...and its a big file with about 50 tabs. Even just some help deleting the other tabs would be greatly appreciated. Also, the data is populated via VLookup, and every time it splits a file it gives me a message asking if I want to update the links? Can the updates be turned on permanently so it splits without any manual input?

Below is some sample data. Please keep in mind that the actual file is far more complex (at least 50 columns)

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn7ms.jpg)

```
    Sub SplitWB()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim OutputFolderName As String
 OutputFolderName = ""
    Set myDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    myDlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
    myDlg.Title = "Select Output Folder for Touchstone Files:"
    If myDlg.Show = -1 Then OutputFolderName = myDlg.SelectedItems(1) & "\" Else Exit Sub
    Set myDlg = Nothing

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim d As Object, c As range, k, tmp As String, unique(500)
    i = 0

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
         i = i + 1
         unique(i) = k
    Next k

    UniqueCount = i

'start deleting

For i = 1 To UniqueCount

    'Actions for new workbook
    wpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    wbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    wsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFolderName & unique(i), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    For j = 1 To lastRow
        If range("A" & j) <> "" And range("A" & j) <> unique(i) Then
            Rows(j).Delete
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Next

    'hide helper columns

'    If HideC = False And DeleteC = True Then
        Columns("A:D").Hidden = True
'    End If
'


    range("E8").Select


    'Select Instructions tab
    'Worksheets("Guidelines").Activate

    'Save new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Workbooks.Open (wpath)

    'ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Workbooks(wbook).Activate

Next


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Macro has completed successfully!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Generated files can be found in the following directory:" & vbNewLine & OutputFolderName)


End Sub
```

Thank you! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:  Put this at the top of your code: `application.AskToUpdateLinks = False` and this at the end `application.AskToUpdateLinks = true`.

Comment: @edwards_mark_86 please mark this as solved if no longer an open issue

Comment: @Jellz77 Only 1 out of 3 issues are resolved. Hopefully by the end of today it will be resolved and marked off. Thanks.

Comment: @Kerry White It most certainly helped, and I upvoted. Unfortunately, I'm too new for my vote to count. Thanks again! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So i think you have a lot of extra code that may not be needed.  i'm going to start out small b/c i'm not sure i fully understand the task at hand.

First, i'm going to create an array for all names in column A.  Next, i'm going to iterate through the array just for the unique values

```
Sub SplitWB()
    Dim namesArray As Variant
    Dim uniqueDict As New dictionary

    namesArray = Range("a1:a4") 'hardcoded the range for now
    Set uniqueDict = New dictionary 

    For x = LBound(namesArray) To UBound(namesArray)
         If Not uniqueDict.Exists(x) Then uniqueDict.Add x, namesArray (x, 1)
    Next x
End Sub
```

The above may not do anything for you just yet, but i notice you're doing unique for loops, etc which aren't necessary.  Just trying to condense your code for ease of debugging.

Once you respond to this, we can work on the next part (you may want to update your code if you use my solution above to create a unique dictionary)

Comment: I just ran the code and its giving me a compile error on 'uniqueDict As New dictionary'. And I like your idea btw...it does seem like a lot of code for such a simple task.

Comment: whoops...make sure to add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference.  Under tools, then reference

Comment: Just tried to run it and tinkered a bit. Nothing is happening when I hit run, not even an error. Any ideas?

Comment: this is just the first step.  just trying to start small.  using your picture example, are you basically trying to send john stevens a report that includes heidi, betty, britney then a report to lindsay that includes tommy, craig, kurt, etc etc

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, but heidi,betty and britney need to be on separate tabs.